# Count characters from string position x to string position y

Tags: php

how do i find how many characters are between the position of a string to another

For example the string might be: brown fox

How do i find how many characters are between 'r' and 'f'?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$r_pos = strpos($str, 'r');
$distance = strpos($str, 'f', $r_pos) - $r_pos - 1;
echo $distance;
```

Comment: Answer is great, but OP needs to show some work before somebody gives it to them on a platter

Answer (score 0):

Using `strpos` ( or `stripos` for case-*insensitive* searching), get the position of "r", and the position of "f". Then, subtract the two.

```
$phrase = "brown fox";
echo stripos( $phrase, "f" ) - stripos( $phrase, "r" );
```

If your sentence can contain an "f" prior to an "r", you can provide an offset for the "f" by passing in the position of "r" as the third argument to `stripos`:

```
$r = stripos( $phrase, "r" );
$f = stripos( $phrase, "f", $r );

echo $f - $r;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "brown fox";
strpos($str,'f') - strpos($str,'r');
```

Comment: serkms is a better answer since it also works if there is an `f`  before the `r`

Comment: @JuanMendes Considering the original question doesn't show much effort in the asking, I gave just a starting point for refinement =)